# Qt 5.6 Passing File Descriptors with QLocalServer and QLocalSocket

Tags: linux, qt, sockets, qt5, file-descriptor

I'm am learning how to pass file descriptors using Unix Domain sockets with Qt 5.6 on Ubuntu 14.04. From the documentation, it sounds like the way to do this is with the QLocalServer and QLocalSocket classes.

I've created 2 simple applications, 1 server and 1 client. They each have only 1 class and I've pasted the entire classes below.

I can receive the 'file descriptor' as an integer, but when I try to open it in append mode so I can write to it in the client process, I get the following error:

```
Cannot open existing file handle:  "Unknown error"
QIODevice::write: device not open
FD Received:  20
```

What am I doing wrong?

Client:

```
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <QtNetwork>

#include "localclient.h"

Client::Client(QObject *parent)
{

    socket = new QLocalSocket(this);
    connect(socket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(readFd()));
    connect(socket, SIGNAL(error(QLocalSocket::LocalSocketError)), this, SLOT(displayError(QLocalSocket::LocalSocketError)));

    requestFd();

}

void Client::requestFd()
{

    socket->abort();
    socket->connectToServer("mysocket");

}

void Client::readFd()
{

    QDataStream in(socket);
    in.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_4_0);

    if (socket->bytesAvailable() < (int)sizeof(quint16))
        return;

    if (in.atEnd())
        return;

    int nextFd;
    in >> nextFd;

    QFile rxFile;
    if ( !rxFile.open(nextFd,QIODevice::Append) ) {
        qDebug() << "Cannot open existing file handle: " << rxFile.errorString();
    }
    rxFile.write("hello");

    qDebug() << "FD Received: " << nextFd;

}

void Client::displayError(QLocalSocket::LocalSocketError socketError)
{
    switch (socketError) {
    case QLocalSocket::ServerNotFoundError:
        tr("The host was not found. Please check the "
           "host name and port settings.");
        break;
    case QLocalSocket::ConnectionRefusedError:
        tr("The connection was refused by the peer. "
           "Make sure the fortune server is running, "
           "and check that the host name and port "
           "settings are correct.");
        break;
    case QLocalSocket::PeerClosedError:
        break;
    default:
        tr("The following error occurred: %1.").arg(socket->errorString());
    }

}
```

Server:

```
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <QtNetwork>

#include <stdlib.h>

#include "localserver.h"
#include <qlocalserver.h>
#include <qlocalsocket.h>

Server::Server(QObject *parent)
{

    server = new QLocalServer(this);
    if (!server->listen("mysocket")) {
        qDebug() << QString("Unable to start the server: %1.").arg(server->errorString());
        return;
    }

    qDebug() << tr("The server is running");

    connect(server, SIGNAL(newConnection()), this, SLOT(sendFd()));

    fileToSend = new QFile("/home/me/Desktop/test.bin");
    if ( !fileToSend->open(QIODevice::WriteOnly) ) {
        qDebug() << "Unable to open file to send";
    }

}

void Server::sendFd()
{

    QByteArray block;
    QDataStream out(&block, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    out.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_4_0);
    out.device()->seek(0);
    qDebug() << "Sending this file handle: " << fileToSend->handle();
    out << fileToSend->handle();

    QLocalSocket *clientConnection = server->nextPendingConnection();
    connect(clientConnection, SIGNAL(disconnected()),
            clientConnection, SLOT(deleteLater()));

    clientConnection->write(block);
    clientConnection->flush();
    clientConnection->disconnectFromServer();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On linux sending file descriptors using Unix domain sockets is done using ancillary data of type `SCM_RIGHTS`. Qt does not seem to support such data using `QLocalSocket` and `QLocalServer`, there is an old [QTBUG](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-16210) talking about the problem. And it seems that it hasn't been solved yet.

you can use the [Qt D-Bus](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtdbus-index.html) where you can send file descriptors using [QDBusUnixFileDescriptor](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdbusunixfiledescriptor.html) class.Or I'm afraid you may have to use Unix domain sockets to implement that yourself, there is a good example [here](http://blog.varunajayasiri.com/passing-file-descriptors-between-processes-using-sendmsg-and-recvmsg).

But are you sure you really need to pass file descriptors between your applications? for purposes other than learning purposes, I think there are always ways to overcome this limitation.

P.S. You are serializing the socket file descriptor using `QDataStream` (as if it was a normal `int`) then send the serialized data for the other process to also read it as a normal `int`. this will allow you to read the integer value of the file descriptor but you will **not** allow you to do any interaction with it since file descriptors values are not meaningful outside the process they belong to.